# How do I clone a hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, clone

I want to completely clone my 250gb drive on my aptop to another 500gb hard drive connected via USB.

The hard drive that is 500gb is blank-it is an upgrade in space for my laptop. I would like to do this for free- I found a similar laptop in a yard sale, but the screen was cracked, but the drive was larger and the memory cards are larger too.

Ideally, I want to clone my 250gb drive to the 500gb drive with Windows and all, then save the 250gb drive as a backup, open my laptop and remove the 250gb drive, replace it with the 500gb drive, and boot-up my laptop back to where I left it when the 250gb drive was in it.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Where have existing guides failed you?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `dd` command within Linux to get an exact copy of you HDD. [Link](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=17&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiH-47RqJ3ZAhWFOJQKHccRAaAQFgiIATAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.thegeekstuff.com%2F2010%2F10%2Fdd-command-examples%2F&usg=AOvVaw1lHPgrWpxztsOiVLR0vYBK).

The command woud go something like this:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

`if` = input file. `of` = output file. In the above example `/dev/sda` is your first HDD, source; and `/dev/sdb` is your target HDD.

Comment: the link does contain 6 ways to solve the preceding question. i added the full command.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no built-in tool for Windows to clone a hard drive. You can use a third-party tool like [EaseUS Todo Backup Home](https://www.easeus.com/backup-utility/copy-and-clone-hard-drive.html).

With this, you can clone your hard drive by:

1. Installing the application;
2. Clicking on *Clone*;
3. Selecting the drive you want to clone, then click *Next*;
4. Selecting the disk you want your data to be put on, then click *Next*; and
5. Clicking on *Proceed*.

If your cloned hard drive shows the same amount of capacity as before, follow these steps to use the maximum capacity of the new hard drive:

1. Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys
2. Type `diskmgmt.msc`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. <kbd>Right Click</kbd> on the drive which shows an incorrect capacity
4. Click *Extend Volume*
5. Finally, follow the wizard in order to use the maximum capacity of your hard drive.

Comment: Just suggesting a tool doesn't really describe how to accomplish what was asked in the question, so your post would be more appropriate as a comment as-is (and might attract downvotes for that reason).  Can you expand it into an actionable solution?

Comment: I added a step-by-step solution into the post.

Comment: @iTechieGamer I did all the steps you said, and it worked well. however now both drive says it has the exact same space used and available.  BUT i know 1 drive is 500gb. How to i fix that?

Comment: @VaroonRamtahal I updated my answer to fix your problem.

Comment: @ iTechieGamer the " Extend Volume" option is not highlighted..please advise.

Comment: @VaroonRamtahal are you sure it's 500GB?

Answer (score -1):

Use a program called Marciom Reflect for windows this will intall a windows CD OS on your windows system from there choose your target drive and source drive and clone .

Comment: Please follow [this outline](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/432690) while recommending software.

Comment: You could try to clone when windows is active from Maricam Reflect but windows / your anti virus may stop Marciam Reflect from accessing some data . If you get "Bad sector " error in marciam reflect this could be because of that .

Comment: And decide whether it's "Marciom", "Maricam" or "Marciam". And [edit] the answer to add important information instead of writing comments.